# Insert data to array using while loop php

Tags: php

I am trying to insert data from database into an array, using while loop, here is my database:

```
  id     resulst  
152556     0
152555     1
152553     1
152552     0
152551     1
152550     0
152549     1
```

Here is the code that I did:

```
$output = [
    "online" => 0,
    "success" => 0,
    "servers" => []
];
$mini_result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `sessions` WHERE status = '1' LIMIT 5");
       while( $result = $mini_result->fetch()){
        
        $output['servers']['mini_result'] = [
            $result['id'] => $result['result']
        ];
       }
$output["online"] = 1;
$output["success"] = 1;

echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```

Output:

```
{
   online: 1,
   success: 1,
   servers: {
        mini_result: {
             152556: "0"
        }
   }
}
```

It only prints 1 element, not 5 as I would like. This is the output I want:

```
{
       online: 1,
       success: 1,
       servers: {
            mini_result: {
                 152556: "0",
                 152555: "1",
                 152553: "1",
                 152552: "0",
                 152551: "1"
            }
       }
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the result on every loop of the loop. What you need to do is:

```
   while($result = $mini_result->fetch()) {
    
    $output['servers']['mini_result'][$result['id']] = $result['result'];
   }
```

This does get quickly quite confusing. You can simplify it, like this:

```
   $miniResult = [];
   while($result = $mini_result->fetch()) {
    
    $miniResult[$result['id']] = $result['result'];
   }
   $output['servers']['mini_result'] = $miniResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

This what u need:

```
$mini_result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `sessions` WHERE status = '1' LIMIT 5");
$output['servers']['mini_result'] = [];
  while( $result = $mini_result->fetch()){
    $output['servers']['mini_result'][$result['id']] = $result['result'];
  }
```